# Best way to unpack class instance kwargs when those kwargs are split up within a method?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class/method which takes kwargs like so:

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, args1-4, **kwargs):
        self.arg = arg
        ...
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def bar():
        obj = obj.method(
            kwarg1 = self.kwargs.pop('kwarg1', 'default'),
            kwarg2 = self.kwargs.pop('kwarg2', 'default')
            )

        obj2 = obj2.other_method(
            kwarg3 = self.kwargs.pop('kwarg3', 'default'),
            kwarg4 = self.kwargs.pop('kwarg4', 'default')
            )
```

That works fine, but looks messy (especially with other args which aren't in my pseudocode).

I've tried multiple configurations of unpacking the kwargs; defining multiple instance variables assigned to `kwargs.pop()` meaning I have 10+ instance variables which are only used once and feels unnecessarily bloated, having the class take default keyword arguments feels equally bloated, and defining variables assigned to `kwargs.pop()` within `bar()` seems unnecessary again given that they're only used once. Having `bar()` take keyword arguments instead feels unnecessarily distinct from `Foo()`.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: If your keyword arguments are only for the instance function `bar`, then I'd avoid having them be instance variables at all. Make them arguments on `bar` instead. Otherwise, `bar` is mutating the state of `Foo` unbeknownst to the user of said object

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thank you!

Comment: Why is `__init__` making `bar` do work it should be doing? `self.kwarg1 = kwargs.get('kwarg1', default)` belongs in `__init__`, not every call to `bar`.

Comment: The `kwarg1` et al should be separate arguments to `__init__`; save `**kwargs` for arguments you don't necessarily know about but need to be passed to `super().__init__` in support of cooperative inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Foo`'s state is changing on a function call, and that is not immediately apparent to the caller. `Foo.kwargs` will change on the call of `Foo.bar`, so if a user calls `Foo.bar` twice, they will get a strange `KeyError` and not know why. To avoid this, just make them arguments on `Foo.bar` itself:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    
    def bar(
        self, 
        obj1, 
        obj2, 
        kwarg1='default', 
        kwarg2='default', 
        kwarg3='default', 
        kwarg4='default'
    ):
        # Do things with kwargs, obj1, and obj2
        pass
```

Comment: Makes sense - thanks for the response.